# How to create a SCNPlane(Like the image I attached below) between two geo locations?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, arkit, scnnode

I am using "Mapbox" framework for AR Navigation and I need to add SCNPlane between the two geo locations like the image below

[image]

// codes - adding SCNNode and SCNPlane

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    // 1

    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    // 2
    let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x )
    let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

    // 3
    plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.lightText

    // 4
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

    // 5
    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    // 6
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

// updating the nodes here

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    // 1
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as?  ARPlaneAnchor,
        let planeNode = node.childNodes.first,
        let plane = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane
        else { return }

    // 2
    let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x + 100)
    let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z )
    plane.width = width
    plane.height = height

    // 3
    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)

}
```

here,I am using ARPlaneAnchor to detect the plane and adding/updating SCNNode using didAdd /didUpdate delegates,but I need to draw SCNPlane between two geo locations without using ARPlaneAnchor.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://medium.com/@yatchoi/getting-started-with-arkit-real-life-waypoints-1707e3cb1da2  https://medium.com/journey-of-one-thousand-apps/arkit-and-corelocation-part-one-fc7cb2fa0150